# How to upload text/csv file data without column mapping on Oracle Apex?

Tags: oracle-apex, oracle-apex-5, oracle-apex-5.1

I have created a table on oracle apex which has almost 50 columns. I want to upload csv or comma/tab separated text data file without column mapping. All I need auto column mapping. Is there any way to accomplish that?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's none.

Data loader, once you create it using the Wizard & run the page, suggests "do not load" as a target for all columns.

If you look at Shared Components / Data Load Definitions, you won't find any settings that would suggest something like "map fields sequentially". Furthermore, none of region attributes nor properties contains anything like that.

As far as I can tell, that can't be done in a declarative manner.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Column Name Aliases under Data Load Definition in Shared Components.
Simply add the names of the CSV and map them to your table columns once and it will do the auto column mapping.